# Copy first file for multiple folders to some another location

Tags: batch-file, desktop-application, file-rename, file-copying

I have about 1000 folders on my hard drive. Each folder contains about 100 .jpg files. Now I need to copy from each folder "page (1).jpg" file in to some specific folder(each folder contain "page (1).jpg" file). And one more thing... On the end, after copying, each .jpg file from specific folder need to have name like folder from which it was copied.

How to do this on easiest way. Maybe with some batch file or something else...

Comment: Described scenario is not completely clear.You need to copy only ONE file to target directory and it should have the name of the source directory?

Comment: Yes this is a problem for for loop but... I am not expert in batch file programming...

Comment: Yes only ONE file and that file is page (1).jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested (you need to change the names of *root_dir* and *target_dir*):

```
@echo off

set "target_dir=E:\scriptests\redirection"
set "root_dir=E:\scriptests\labels"
pushd %root_dir%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in  ('dir /b /s  "page ?1?.jpg"') do (
    set "fdir=%%~dpa"
    set stripped=!fdir:~0,-1!
   for %%# in ("!stripped!") do ( 
     echo %%~n#
     set "dir_name=%%~n#"
    )
   copy /y "%%~fa" "%target_dir%\!dir_name!.jpg"  >nul 2>nul
) 
endlocal 
popd
pause
```

Comment: I tested your program and on the end in target folder is only one file with empty name.